# Apollo fetch cancels on escape key press

Tags: javascript, fetch, apollo-client

I'm using `apollo-client@2.3.5` (but this problem also occurs on latest version and might not be directly related to Apollo Client itself).

I use several requests to load different parts of my app. My problem is that `Escape` key press cancels fetch requests, and breaks whole app. I already tried:

- capturing `Escape` keydown event and calling `preventDefault()`, `stopPropagation()`, `return false`
- removing `signal` field from fetch request options
- overriding fetch in Apollo Client to use axios (but it's impossible as axios is not compatible with Fetch API)

But still requests are cancelled on `Escape` key press.

Is there any workaround or way to prevent fetch requests from being cancelled? Or maybe there is some client compatible with Fetch API which doesn't cancel requests on `Escape` key press?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stumbling across the same or similar issue, I managed to work around it like this:

1. I have created following function:

   ```
   export const makeRequest = (url, requestParams) => {
       requestParams.data = requestParams.body;

       return axios(url, requestParams)
           .then(response => {
               return new Response(JSON.stringify(response.data), {
                   ...response.headers,
                   status: response.status,
                   statusText: response.statusText
               })
           });
   };
   ```
2. I replaced default fetch in Apollo Link in Apollo Client using `fetch` property:

   ```
   new HttpLink({
       uri: config.graphqlUrl,
       credentials: 'same-origin',
       fetch: makeRequest
   })
   ```

`makeRequest` function mimics `fetch`, but is not cancelled with `Escape` key press.

Apollo client expects response to be instance of [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response), so we provide it with one.

EDIT:
It turned out that it does not work on IE11. If you care about IE compatibility, you should install `whatwg-fetch` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/whatwg-fetch) and on top of the file include following:

```
import { Response } from "whatwg-fetch";
```